# on mouseover and mouse move Tooltip's tip is not working as expected in D3 js Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my D3 chart, I have Implemented Zoom in and Zoom out functionality after adding this I am facing some issue with tooltip, It is not showing data on hover for that dot/circle as expected. (I feel after adding zoom in zoom out newX and newY is not updated properly)

Working code for tooltip without zoom in zoom out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bell-qqwwe)

After adding the zoom in zoom out code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h)

```
.on("mousemove", function() {
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        var mouseDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]);
        var i = bisectDate(data, mouseDate); // returns the index to the current data item

        var d0 = data[i - 1];
        var d1 = data[i];
        let d;
        // work out which date value is closest to the mouse
        if (typeof d1 !== "undefined") {
          d = mouseDate - d0.startTime > d1.startTime - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;
        } else {
          d = d0;
        }

        div
          .html(
            `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
                         <span>Magnitude: ${d.magnitude} </span>`
          )
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
        var x = xScale(d.startTime);
        var y = yScale(d.magnitude);

        focus
          .select("#focusCircle")
          .attr("cx", x)
          .attr("cy", y);
        focus
          .select("#focusLineX")
          .attr("x1", x)
          .attr("y1", yScale(yDomain[0]))
          .attr("x2", x)
          .attr("y2", yScale(yDomain[1]));
        focus
          .select("#focusLineY")
          .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
          .attr("y1", y)
          .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
          .attr("y2", y);
      });
```

I am not able to differentiate why there's an issue. Please help me.

Comment: as long as my concern the title is miss-match i thing the data is right but the tip has a delay or whatever, you put the wrong title or i have miss understanding?

Comment: Updated the title. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious of your code i never see the tip function build like this, wrong but its works

See the one without zoom build,

if you change

```
g.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {....
```

to

```
svg
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {....
```

it will produce the same issue

> You make a wasting element, see the one without zoom build

```
g.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {....
```

you should not do that, why you `selectAll ("dot")` and `append ('rect')`, please read more `d3.js` documentation and why you do this anyway, you build all rectangle element each one of data for overlay and stay hidden? for what? you even not using the data that append to it, why not just make it one rect element

```
g.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {....
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {....
```

now back to the one who has a zoom on it, when your mouse pointing to that svg which element your pointer point to? to the bottom of svg layer or the first one? pointer not pointing to that element and you put an event such as mousemove, your mouse pointer never touch that element, it will not works,i believe you know why, that is why this code put mouse event and zoom function to the svg, but it produces some issue you face it now, just make a little adjustment to that two code and all will be done

```js
var data = [
      {
        startTime: "1567765320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1567851720049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568024520049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: 10,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568283720049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568629320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1569061320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1569579720049",
        magnitude: -20,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1570184520049",
        magnitude: -20,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1570875720049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1571653320049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: -0,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1572517320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1573467720049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1574504520049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1575627720049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      }
    ];
    
      
  var drawLineGraph = function(containerHeight, containerWidth, data, yLabel, warnLine) {
    // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
    var newX = '' 
    const updateChart = () => {
      d3.select("#focusCircle").style('display', 'none')
      // recover the new scale
      newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
      var newY = yScale;


      // update axes with these new boundaries
      d3.select("#axisX").call(d3.axisBottom(newX));
      //d3.select('#axisY').call(d3.axisLeft(newY));

      // update circle position
      scatter
        .selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          if (d) {
            return newX(d.startTime);
          }
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          if (d) {
            return newY(d.magnitude);
          }
        });

      var line2 = d3
        .line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return newX(d.startTime);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return newY(d.startupMagnitude);
        });

      var area = d3
        .area()
        .x(function(d) {
          return newX(d.startTime);
        })
        .y0(function(d) {
          return yScale(d.startupMagnitude);
        })
        .y1(height);

      var line = d3
        .line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return newX(d.startTime);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return newY(d.magnitude);
        });

        g.select('#firstLayer').on("mousemove", function() {
        d3.select("#focusCircle").style('display', 'block')
         focus.style('display', 'none')
          var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
          var mouseDate = newX.invert(mouse[0]);
          var i = bisectDate(data, mouseDate); // returns the index to the current data item
  
          var d0 = data[i - 1];
          var d1 = data[i];
          let d;
          // work out which date value is closest to the mouse
          if ( typeof d1 !== "undefined" && typeof d0 !== "undefined"){
                    focus.style('display', 'block')
          div.style('display', 'block')
            if (typeof d1 !== "undefined" ) {
                d = mouseDate - d0.startTime > d1.startTime - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;
            } else {
              d = d0;
            }
            
                      div
            .html(
              `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
          <span>Magnitude: ${d.magnitude} </span>`
            )
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
          var x = newX(d.startTime);
          var y = yScale(d.magnitude);
  
          focus
            .select("#focusCircle")
            .attr("cx", x)
            .attr("cy", y);
          focus
            .select("#focusLineX")
            .attr("x1", x)
            .attr("y1", yScale(yDomain[0]))
            .attr("x2", x)
            .attr("y2", yScale(yDomain[1]));
          focus
            .select("#focusLineY")
            .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
            .attr("y1", y)
            .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
            .attr("y2", y);
          } else {
          d3.select("#focusCircle").style('display', 'none')
          focus.style('display', 'none')
          div.style('display', 'none')
          
          }

  

        });

      scatter.select("#line2").attr("d", line2);
      scatter.select(".line").attr("d", line);
      scatter.select("#area").attr("d", area);
    };

    var zoom = d3
      .zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0.5, 20]) // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
      .extent([[0, 0], [containerWidth, containerHeight]])
      .on("zoom", updateChart);

    var svg = d3
      .select('#chart')
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", containerWidth)
      .attr("height", containerHeight);

    var clip = svg
      .append("defs")
      .append("SVG:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("SVG:rect")
      .attr("width", containerWidth)
      .attr("height", containerHeight)
      .attr("x", 50)
      .attr("y", 0);

    // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
    var scatter = svg.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    var margin = { top: 50, left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 80 };

    var height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

    var xDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.startTime;
    });
    var yDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.magnitude;
    });

    var xScale = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(xDomain);
    var yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .domain(yDomain);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

    var line = d3
      .line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.magnitude);
      });

    var line2 = d3
      .line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.startupMagnitude);
      });

    var area = d3
      .area()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      // .x0(function(d) {
      //   return xScale(d.startTime);
      // })
      // .x1(function(d) {
      //   return xScale(d.magnitude);
      // })
      .y0(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.startupMagnitude);
      })
      .y1(height);
    // .y0(height)
    // .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.magnitude); });

    // var area = d3
    //   .area()
    //   .x0(function(d) {
    //     return xScale(d.startTime);
    //   })
    //   .x1(function(d) {
    //     return xScale(d.startTime);
    //   })
    //   .y0(function(d) {
    //     return yScale(d.magnitude);
    //   })
    //   .y1(function(d) {
    //     return yScale(0);
    //   });

    // var area = d3
    //   .area()
    //   .x(function(d) {
    //     return xScale(d.startTime);
    //   })
    //   .y0(function(d) {
    //     return yScale(d.magnitude);
    //   })
    //   .y1(yScale(0));

    // Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    var g = scatter
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
      
    var g2 = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

    g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("id", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("id", "axisX")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    g2.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("id", "axisY")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(yLabel);

    g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")

      .attr("d", line);

    g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line2")
      .attr("id", "line2")
      .attr("d", line2);

    g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.magnitude);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        if (d.startupRunningStatus === "OUT_OF_SYNC") {
          return 5;
        }
      })
      .attr("class", "circle");

    //legend code
    svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 40)
      .attr("cy", 380)
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style("fill", "#1391d8");
    svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 40)
      .attr("cy", 400)
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style("fill", "red");
    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 60)
      .attr("y", 380)
      .text("Startup Config")
      .style("font-size", "15px")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");
    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 60)
      .attr("y", 400)
      .text("Running Config")
      .style("font-size", "15px")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");

    // focus tracking
    var focus = g.append("g").style("display", "none");

    focus
      .append("line")
      .attr("id", "focusLineX")
      .attr("class", "focusLine");
    focus
      .append("line")
      .attr("id", "focusLineY")
      .attr("class", "focusLine");
    focus
      .append("circle")
      .attr("id", "focusCircle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("class", "circle focusCircle");

    //grid line
    const make_x_axis = () => {
      return d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    };

    scatter
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50," + (height + 50) + ")")
      .call(
        make_x_axis()
          .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
          .tickFormat("")
      );

    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
      return d.startTime;
    }).left;
    var parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    g
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("id","firstLayer")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)

      
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log('ok')
        focus.style("display", null);
        div
          .transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", 0.9);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        focus.style("display", "none");
        div
          .transition()
          .duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      })

      .on("mousemove", function() {
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        var mouseDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]);
        var i = bisectDate(data, mouseDate); // returns the index to the current data item

        var d0 = data[i - 1];
        var d1 = data[i];
        let d;
        // work out which date value is closest to the mouse
        if (typeof d1 !== "undefined") {
          d = mouseDate - d0.startTime > d1.startTime - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;
        } else {
          d = d0;
        }

        div
          .html(
            `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
        <span>Magnitude: ${d.magnitude} </span>`
          )
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
        var x = xScale(d.startTime);
        var y = yScale(d.magnitude);

        focus
          .select("#focusCircle")
          .attr("cx", x)
          .attr("cy", y);
        focus
          .select("#focusLineX")
          .attr("x1", x)
          .attr("y1", yScale(yDomain[0]))
          .attr("x2", x)
          .attr("y2", yScale(yDomain[1]));
        focus
          .select("#focusLineY")
          .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
          .attr("y1", y)
          .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
          .attr("y2", y);
      })

      .call(zoom);

    // warn line

    // if (
    //   warnLine &&
    //   yDomain[0] < warnLine.lineValue &&
    //   yDomain[1] > warnLine.lineValue
    // ) {
    //   g.append("line")
    //     .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
    //     .attr("y1", yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
    //     .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
    //     .attr("y2", yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
    //     .attr("class", "zeroline");
    //   g.append("text")
    //     .attr("x", xScale(xDomain[1]))
    //     .attr("y", yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
    //     .attr("dy", "1em")
    //     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    //     .text(warnLine.label)
    //     .attr("class", "zerolinetext");
    // }
  }
  
    drawLineGraph(410, 700, data, "Magnitude", {
      lineValue: 0,
      label: "Startup Config!"
    });
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e0e0e0;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.line2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2e59cf;
  stroke-width: 0.3px;
}

.circle {
  /* fill: white;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px; */
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: steelblue;
  /* stroke-width: 2px; */
}

.area {
  fill: #2e59cf;
  stroke: none;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.zeroline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #1391d8;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 8 8;
}

.zerolinetext {
  fill: #1391d8;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focusLine {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

.focusCircle {
  fill: red;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-width: 0.7px;
  stroke-dasharray: 8 8;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="App">
  <h1>Chart</h1>
  </div>
 <div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input again, I am new to D3 js and still trying to understand the stuff. I did the cleanup and you suggested and you are only using .call(zoom); in bottom.

But I am seeing issue is still present when we do zoom in zoom out. because we have svg.on in updated chart

Comment: dude i think we have communication, i don't get what you mean, what exactly your problem, that's is, you know the problem we have svg.on in updated, why not change svg to g ? please check my updated answer, and if you still have problem please can you describe more of your problem, tell me the output you want

Comment: Bro problem was inside updateChart we were using svg.on and this should be g.on which you have updated in your answer. Problem was after zoom in behaviour was little different like mouse hover tooltip was not coming properly. you can change the code and check.

Your answer worked totally fine for me. Thanks again..

Comment: i find some issue on that answer that is when you zoom it the tooltip will coming out on empty space, event it without chart on that range of time, just it  sorry.. i update it again, but what is the meaning of not coming properly? the animation or what?

Comment: no, you don't, i found a new one when you drag it, it will still have a dot on the left top corner, to produce it try to drag it further left

Comment: yes your are correct there is issue, why you have added g.select('#firstLayer') on place of g..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199294/discussion-between-javascript-coder-and-kekuatan).

Comment: if we add g.select('#firstLayer') on place of g. again same problem with mouse over occurs

Comment: Yes because g contains many elements i just need to select the first element not all of that, that's means all element under g have mouseover event, the chart is working but not a good approach, heavy and sometimes cause some bug. that is some problems but that is not the main point that causes this, the point is you need to add a limit on when tip show up because you have zoom functionality who change your domain and range on the chart, see my update answer, sorry for mess code, cheers

Comment: Differently Make sense. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am going to remove the focus line and tooltip on mousemove because still I see when we drap the graph to left when no data is there one red focus circle with tooltip comes, any suggestions how i can limit the code so that no bugs are present for future.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h Updated codesandbox removed focus lines, Need to remove tooltip when there is no data. this code on mousemove . -  div
          .html(
            `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
             <span>Magnitude: ${d.magnitude} </span>`
          )
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
        var x = xScale(d.startTime);
        var y = yScale(d.magnitude);